# How can I easily monitor changes to my reputation score? Is there a Firefox extension available?

Tags: discussion, reputation, firefox

Suppose a user has put some time and effort into asking and answering
questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/),
[Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or any of the most popular [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)
sites. How can that user keep up-to-date with his or her scores on these
sites and be alerted to any changes? Is there perhaps a Firefox extension
which could help?

Answer (score 7):

I have just uploaded [Stack Overflow Reputation Display](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/53142), a new
Firefox extension to the Mozilla addon site which allows you to
monitor the scores of one or more accounts on a dozen or so Stack
Overflow-like sites.

Details of your reputation score and badge counts for your
account(s) are shown unobtrusively in the status bar, and are updated
periodically. Optional sound effects can draw your attention to any
changes.

[image: Firefox status bar showing reputation score and badge counts]

The extension is currently in the Mozilla add-ons sandbox awaiting
feedback from reviewers and users, but I am hoping that it will be
promoted to official public status before long.

If you would like to install this extension, you can [download it
here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/53142).

Comment: Any chance of getting customisable colours in there? Doesn't play well with black themes, unfortunately!

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that. I'll add that asap.

Comment: Now updated, as requested. Fancy writing a review on the addons.mozilla.org website? I'm going to need some positive user reviews to get it approved.

Comment: @Tim - can you allow people to insert an arbitrary URL for a stackexchange site - I'd like to use this specifically for chiphacker, but there are others I'd also like to use.  Thanks again for the plugin!

Comment: Sorry, only just seen this. That's an excellent idea. It'll take a bet of a rewrite of some of the code, but it'll probably be worth it. I'll think about how I can sensibly add it in.

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim. i've tested your addon and works properly on Windows XP.It does not seem to work on Windows 2003 and 0sx Leopard, i just can see the icons right-bottom but without any score and User in addons properties is greyed out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the microsummary XML file found here for FF:

[Firefox users - your Stack Overflow “reputation” microsummary!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/firefox-users-your-stackoverflow-reputation-microsummary)

specifically [this answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/firefox-users-your-stack-overflow-reputation-microsummary/12372#12372)

You just have to add bookmarks to your summary page into your bookmark toolbar and use the "live title" option for the name. You get something akin to:

[alt text http://sam.haslers.info/images/SO-SF-microsummaries.png](http://sam.haslers.info/images/SO-SF-microsummaries.png)

Comment: Most excellent!

Answer (score 1):

This add-on is great! However, I just discovered that it is not compatible with Firefox 3.6 :(

Feature request: what do you think about adding an indicator of new messages (i.e. the same as the orange envelope icon)?

Bug report: sometimes it stops updating (perhaps related to having a humongous number of tabs open, which I usually do); also, if there is more than one browser window open, usually only one of the windows will continue to update, and then if that window is closed the other window(s) do not resume updating, either.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've now updated the details on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/53142 to specify 3.6 compatibility, but I haven't yet tested it personally.

I'll also look into the bug you mention - thanks for the report. If you're interested in finding out more, setting extensions.sorepdisplay.debug to true will give more debug information into the error console.

Lastly, a positive review on the Mozilla site https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/53142 would be very helpful to support my getting the extension formal approval.

Glad you like it!

Comment: @Tim: I shall comply! :)

Comment: @Tim: it appears things are a little broken in Firefox 3.6.6: on OSX, only meta updates; the other sites in the trilogy display '-' in the status bar as if I am not logged in even though I am.  Also, the bug I report above still persists (only one window gets the updates).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jon Skeet's reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx). It's maybe not as convenient as a Firefox extension, but I usually use Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I made a extension for Chrome to do this a while ago ([SOFURep](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/sofurep/) in case anyone is interested), but since custom toolbars for extensions has been discontinued, it no longer works (although I haven't tried it on the latest dev build).

I would be good if there was an official extension/plugin/addin for this for the major browsers - perhaps either written by the SO team, or an officially adopted one. I only wrote one because there wasn't one available - it seems silly for many people to reinvent this same wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Windows batch script that downloads the user profile HTML from 6 sites (SOFU and 2 Stack Exchange sites) using [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) and a Perl one-liner for each to extract the reputation information and appends it to a text file, SOscores.txt, together with a timestamp. Thus SOscores.txt is also a permanent record of reputation over time.

At the end SOscores.txt is opened in the program that opens .txt files, e.g. UltraEdit. This script would be similar on Linux and Mac OS X. It could be made simpler by some refactoring.

```
    %WGLOC%  http://stackoverflow.com/users/63550       %OUTFOLDER%\SO.html
    %WGLOC%  http://serverfault.com/users/5144          %OUTFOLDER%\SF.html
    %WGLOC%  http://superuser.com/users/517             %OUTFOLDER%\SU.html
    %WGLOC%  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550  %OUTFOLDER%\mSO.html
    %WGLOC%  http://sciencestack.com/users/81           %OUTFOLDER%\SS.html
    %WGLOC%  http://mathoverflow.net/users/2022         %OUTFOLDER%\MO.html

    echo.  >> SOscores.txt
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------- >> SOscores.txt
    echo State %date%T%time%: >> SOscores.txt

    rem Note: the different aligment here is to make the output
    rem       line up with current reputation values.
    perl -nle "print '  Stack Overflow       ' . $1 . '  (no change)' if /\s{20,99}([0-9,]{3,6})<\/div>/;" "%OUTFOLDER_RAW%\SO.html"    >> SOscores.txt
    perl -nle "print '  Server Fault           ' . $1 . '  (no change)' if /\s{20,99}([0-9,]{3,6})<\/div>/;" "%OUTFOLDER_RAW%\SF.html"  >> SOscores.txt
    perl -nle "print '  Super User           ' . $1 . '  (no change)' if /\s{20,99}([0-9,]{3,6})<\/div>/;" "%OUTFOLDER_RAW%\SU.html"  >> SOscores.txt
    perl -nle "print '  Meta Stack Overflow    ' . $1 . '  (no change)' if /\s{20,99}([0-9,]{3,6})<\/div>/;" "%OUTFOLDER_RAW%\mSO.html" >> SOscores.txt
    perl -nle "print '  Science Stack           ' . $1 . '  (no change)' if /\s{20,99}([0-9,]{2,6})<\/div>/;" "%OUTFOLDER_RAW%\SS.html"  >> SOscores.txt
    perl -nle "print '  Math Overflow            ' . $1 . '  (no change)' if /\s{20,99}([0-9,]{1,6})<\/div>/;" "%OUTFOLDER_RAW%\MO.html"  >> SOscores.txt
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------- >> SOscores.txt

    rem Open result in default program for TXT files, e.g. UltraEdit.
    SOscores.txt
```

`%WGLOC%` is an environment variable with the full path to wget and some parameters for it.